# Copy a random file to another location (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to get a random file from a folder and copy it to another folder;

So, I get the files in the folder

```
root_src = 'D:\Downloads'
files = os.listdir(root_src)
file = random.choice(files)
new_root = os.path.join(root_src, 'new') 

copyfile(file, new_path)
```

I get the following error:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file-12.jpg'
```

So, I guess when I do random.choice I don't get the path

Comment: I think the error is pretty obvious. `file` is `file-12.jpg` without the directory. You may want something like`os.path.join(root_src, file)`.

Comment: Also, are you trying to copy to `new_root`? what is `new_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
import os
root_src = 'D:\Downloads'
files = os.listdir(root_src)
file = random.choice(files)
new_root = os.path.join(root_src, 'new') 

copyfile(os.path.join(root_src, file), new_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.listdir), it returns a list of the **names** of files in the folder.

It does not join those file names to the directory path (something of a consequence of the design choice of having strings masquerade as paths without any explicit `Path` object a la Java).

Wherever it is this problem emerges, you need to join them. To do this, `from os import path` and invoke [`path.join(root_src, file)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Note that if you use `path` as a variable name, you shouldn't do this. Rather, `import os` and invoke `os.path.join(root_src, file)`.